# Is it normal for a French Insurance company to delay repairing my vehicle for three months?

Tags: car-insurance, france

I'm insured with one of France's largest insurers. In June there was a huge hail in central France, lots of cars were severely damaged. Since then, only the windshield has been replaced on my car. In July I finally brought my vehicle in for an expertise. The expert told me it would quickly send the repair quote to my insurer. Now it's September and the insurer has not received the numbers. The insurer has inquired with the expert several times, but the expert has not so far delivered the repair quote.

Is this normal for a French insurer? Is there a recourse? I've asked the insurer if it can make me an appointment with another expert to maybe speed up the things, but the insurer said it was okay because there were 10,000 hail claims.

It seems to me the insurer, or the expert, or both, are kind of playing a game with me.

Comment: Why the quotes around "cannot"?

Comment: To be more clear: your actual problem is that the "expert" (mechanic?) has not sent the quote to your insurance for three months. Sounds like the mechanic is at fault, since your insurance hasn't received anything.

Comment: Have you tried a different expert?

Comment: @DJClayworth The insurance company says that "everything is in order", and "we just need to wait", something along those lines. No other expert seems a possibility.

Comment: @Nosjack I've asked the insurance company a couple of times to make an appointment with another expert, but it won't do that.

Answer (score 1):

There is a major shortage of car parts at the moment.  Lead times of several months are common.

They could be waiting for all the parts to arrive.  Or maybe there's such a backlog of cars at the repair shop that there's no point in booking yours in yet.

Comment: Lack of parts is no reason not to deliver a quote.

Comment: It is yet to be determined what parts need to arrive.